# GCM messaging returns "NotRegistered" (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.android

I have successfully sent GCM messages to my Xamarin application before, but for some reason they are failing now. The POST request returns NotRegistered. My code is as follows:

Android Manifest:

```
<application android:label="MyProject">
  <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
      <category android:name="com.example.MyProject" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
</application>
```

Instance ID listener service:

```
[Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" })]
class InstanceIdListenerService : InstanceIDListenerService
{
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(RegistrationIntentService));
        StartService(intent);
    }
}
```

Registration intent service (this is created in the main activity):

```
static object locker = new object();

protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance(this);
        var token = instanceID.GetToken(
            "123456789123",
            GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, 
            null);
        SendRegistrationToAppServer(token); // just a HTTP request
    }
}
```

GCM listener service:

```
[Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" })]
class GcmLstnrService : GcmListenerService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(string from, Bundle data)
    {
        string msg = data.GetString("message");
        Log.Info("GcmLstnrService", "From: " + from);
        Log.Info("GcmLstnrService", "Msg: " + msg);
    }
}
```

The POST response:

```
{"multicast_id":8322296108700959972,
"success":0,
"failure":1,
"canonical_ids":0,
"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

What's wrong? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have a call to GcmClient.Register() anywhere in your code?

Comment: No I don't, apparently I should? Where should I add that?
Isn't GcmClient some sort of a plugin?

Comment: I double checked and it seems like calling Register() is the old, deprecated way to register for GCM. I didn't worked with the new approach yet: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/legacy-regid

Answer (score 4):

I solved this with a rather ugly hack. It seems that the token/instance ID had expired, so I added:

```
var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance(this);

// update the instance ID
instanceID.DeleteInstanceID();
instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance(this);

var token = instanceID.GetToken(
    "123456789123", 
    GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, 
    null);
```

I could refine this solution by only updating the instance ID when the response from GCM is NotRegistered.